# MySQL's INSTR and collations

Tags: mysql, collation

EDIT 3: OK, forget all the complicated stuff below. My question is as easy as this: Why is the second column of the following result set 0 while all other columns are 1.

```
SELECT 'a' = 'á',
       INSTR('András','Andras'), 
       'András' LIKE 'Andras',
       INSTR('András','Andräs')
```

The database and connection is set to utf8.

END EDIT

I've got an issue with MySQL's INSTR function. I have a table 'values' with collation utf8_general_ci and a VARCHAR column 'value' containing the value 'András Schiff'. Now I perform the following queries:

```
> SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
> SELECT 'a' = 'á';
1
> SELECT * FROM values WHERE value LIKE '%Andras%'
'András'
> SELECT * FROM values WHERE INSTR(value,'Andras')
(Empty)
> SELECT * FROM values WHERE INSTR(value,'Andräs')
'András'
```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior? I thought LIKE '%...%' and INSTR were equivalent, the latter having the advantage that the search string may contain '%'.

Thanks

EDIT: My MySQL version is Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.54, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

EDIT 2: Another thing I noticed:

```
> SELECT * FROM values WHERE INSTR(value,'Andras') COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

gives an error "COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'". But I don't understand why the character set should be binary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSTR(str,substr) does not work when str contains 'é' or 'ë' and substr only 'e'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923186/instrstr-substr-does-not-work-when-str-contains-e-or-e-and-substr-only-e)

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the Edit 2 portion concerning INSTR and COLLATE

The following syntax works for me

```
SELECT * FROM values WHERE INSTR(value COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,'Andras')
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command for a database mydb

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

Example Output:

```
mysql> show create database conversationminer;
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database          | Create Database                                                              |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| conversationminer | CREATE DATABASE `conversationminer` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */ |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just take note of the character set of the database.

Also, do this

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE values\G
```

Just take note of the character set of the table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The database's character set was indeed latin1, but changing the collation did not solve the problem. The table has utf8 as default charset.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it is a bug in Mysql.

I have mysql version "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.67, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1" and it errors "COLLATION 'utf8_swedish_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary'".

In other server using "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.27, for Linux (i686) using readline 5.1" and no errors although identical databases in both.

So updating mysql could solve the problem.