# INSTR(str,substr) does not work when str contains 'é' or 'ë' and substr only 'e'

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

In another post on stackoverflow, I read that `INSTR` could be used to order results by relevance.

My understanding of `col LIKE '%str%' and`INSTR(col, 'str')` is that they both behave the same. There seems to be a difference in how collations are handled.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO users (name)
VALUES ('Joël'), ('René');

SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%joel%'; -- 1 record returned
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%rene%'; -- 1 record returned
SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR(name, 'joel') > 0; -- 0 records returned
SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR(name, 'rene') > 0; -- 0 records returned
SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR(name, 'joël') > 0; -- 1 record returned
SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR(name, 'rené') > 0; -- 1 record returned
```

Although `INSTR` does some conversion, it finds `ë` in `é`.

```
SELECT INSTR('é', 'ë'), INSTR('é', 'e'), INSTR('e', 'ë');
-- returns 1, 0, 0
```

Am I missing something?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bf21/6 (using mysql-version: 5.5.22)

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393724/mysqls-instr-and-collations?rq=1

Comment: Thx. Does not seem to provide an answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to [bug 70767 on `LOCATE()` and `INSTR()`](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70767), which has been verified.

Though the [`INSTR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) documentation states that it can be used for multi-byte strings, it doesn't seem to work, as you note, with collations like `utf8_general_ci`, which [should be case and accent insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-implementations.html)

> This function is multi-byte safe, and is case sensitive only if at least one argument is a binary string.

The bug report states that although MySQL does this correctly it only does so when the number of *bytes* is also identical:

> However, you can easily observe that they do not (completely) respect collations when looking for one string inside another one. It seems that what's happening is that MySQL looks for a substring which is collation-equal to the target **which has exactly the same length in bytes** as the target. This is only rarely true.

To pervert the reports example, if you create the following table:

```
create table t ( needle varchar(10), haystack varchar(10)
                  ) COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
insert into t values ("A", "a"), ("A", "XaX");
insert into t values ("A", "á"), ("A", "XáX");
insert into t values ("Á", "a"), ("Á", "XaX");
insert into t values ("Å", "á"), ("Å", "XáX");
```

then run this query, you can see the same behaviour demonstrated:

```
select needle
     , haystack
     , needle=haystack as `=`
     , haystack LIKE CONCAT('%',needle,'%') as `like`
     , instr(needle, haystack) as `instr`
  from t;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4fbf/2)

Comment: Impressive research. Thanks for confirming this is an actual MySQL bug. Are there any known workarounds?

Comment: Use LIKE @mlangenberg :-). It doesn't rely on byte-length for equality but does the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but the sole reason to try this approach was to `ORDER BY INSTR(name, substr)`, so most relevant results would be listed first. I noticed records in my result set that would match the `LIKE`, but return 0 for `INSTR`, and that should not happen.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it is a solid answer to my question: a bug in MySQL.

Comment: I'm not sure how INSTR() provides the most relevant results @mlangenberg. It returns the index one string in another, 0 if there's no match. This means that you return the least likely results first. All others are correct...

Comment: You are right. I am doing a `WHERE name LIKE '%substr%' ORDER BY INSTR(name, substr)`. There should always be match. That is actually how I found this bug, I saw a least likely result (containing ô) at first.