# Sort mySQL results by the position (index) of a string in a text field

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry if this is duplicate question, but I could'nt find anything helpful here.

So, what I'm trying to do, is to sort the results of my mySQL statement by the position of a query string inside the `title` field. I tried to do this with the INSTR function, and this kinda works (even though the first result is wrong because it has an umlaut in it – maybe you also have an explanation for that = bonus points). My statement looks like this (query string is 'all' in this case):

```
SELECT title, translation, INSTR(title, 'all') as posititon
FROM `dictionary` 
WHERE title LIKE '%all%' 
ORDER BY posititon
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

So far, so good. But I also want to have results that match the query string in the field 'description'. So when I add `OR translation LIKE '%all%'` in the WHERE clause, I get a totally different result:

```
SELECT title, translation, INSTR(title, 'all') as posititon
FROM `dictionary` 
WHERE (title LIKE '%all%' OR translation LIKE '%all%')
ORDER BY posititon
```

Result:

[image]

So my goal would be to sort the result PRIMARY by the position of the query string in the field 'title' and SECONDARY by the position of the query string in the field 'translation'.

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: `ORDER BY INSTR(title, 'all'), INSTR(translation, 'all')`  ?

Comment: No, this gives me the exact same result as shown in the second image

Comment: You added like by translation in the WHERE-part. This added new rows to the result of query. But columns still the same, where position just in the title. So, you need te add new column with position in translation, as proposed @Luuk, and add this column also to the `ORDER BY part`: 1. `INSTR(title, 'all') position1, INSTR(translation, 'all') position2` `order by position1, position2`

Comment: As far as I can tell, @Luuk gave you the correct answer.  If it's not what you want, (and even if it is) you should include the desired output in your question.  For that matter, you should at also include schema and sample data for sql questions.  Better yet, a sql fiddle. Images of tables of data are generally a bad idea.

Comment: Please also read this: [INSTR(str,substr) does not work when str contains 'é' or 'ë' and substr only 'e'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923186/instrstr-substr-does-not-work-when-str-contains-%c3%a9-or-%c3%ab-and-substr-only-e)

Comment: Sorry if my question was misleading, and for providing only screenshots. My next issue will be more comprehensible. Eventually, the answer user1191247 provided solved my issue. But also thanks to Luuk and the rest of you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not deal with the accent-sensitivity issue, addressed in [Luuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77293653/sort-mysql-results-by-the-position-index-of-a-string-in-a-text-field#77293951).

Because both [INSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) and [REGEXP_INSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr) return `0` when the needle is not found, you need to change the `0` to something else to stop them coming first in the sort.

Here's one way:

```sql
WITH dictionary (title, translation) AS (
    VALUES
        ROW('Mistkäll', 'Mistkerl'),
        ROW('all', 'alle, aufgerbraucht - '),
        ROW('Toa', 'Tor (Fußball)'),
        ROW('ball', 'something'),
        ROW('something', 'ball'),
        ROW('something', 'all'),
        ROW('small', 'something')
)
SELECT
    title,
    translation,
    NULLIF(INSTR(title, 'all'), 0) as ti_pos,
    NULLIF(INSTR(translation, 'all'), 0) as tr_pos
FROM `dictionary` 
WHERE (title LIKE '%all%' OR translation LIKE '%all%')
ORDER BY -ti_pos DESC, -tr_pos DESC;
```

`-ti_pos DESC` is the same as `ti_pos ASC` but with the NULLs moved to the end.

Outputs:

| title | translation | ti_pos | tr_pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| all | alle, aufgerbraucht - | 1 | 1 |
| ball | something | 2 |  |
| small | something | 3 |  |
| something | all |  | 1 |
| something | ball |  | 2 |
| Toa | Tor (Fußball) |  | 10 |
| Mistkäll | Mistkerl |  |  |

Or for something where the intent is more obvious:

```sql
SELECT
    title,
    translation,
    INSTR(title, 'all') as ti_pos,
    INSTR(translation, 'all') as tr_pos
FROM `dictionary` 
WHERE (title LIKE '%all%' OR translation LIKE '%all%')
ORDER BY IF(ti_pos = 0, 99999999, ti_pos), IF(tr_pos = 0, 99999999, tr_pos);
```

Comment: Or `ORDER BY ti_pos = 0, ti_pos, tr_pos = 0, tr_pos`

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you for solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think [regexp_like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) may help for getting the position:

```
with cte as (
   select 'Mistkäll' as title 
   union all 
   select 'all' 
   union all
   select 'cow')
select 
   title, 
   regexp_instr(title,'[aä]ll')  regexp1
from cte
order by regexp1;
```

output:

| title | regexp1 |
| --- | --- |
| cow | 0 |
| all | 1 |
| Mistkäll | 6 |

Note: of course you need to expand the regular expression (`[aä]`) with all possible values like `á`, `à`, etc.